# Using vector as defrecord fields

Tags: clojure

I want to create a record whose field names are defined elsewhere. So something like this,

```
(def myFields [(symbol "field1") (symbol "field2")])

(defrecord myRecord myFields)
```

which only resulted in the error,

```
Unexpected error (AssertionError) macroexpanding defrecord at (Snippets.clj:57:1).
No fields vector given.
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: @MartinPůda It's obviously the same question, but as "just use `eval`" is a pretty bad answer, I'm not inclined to close it as a dupe. A good answer would be "Attempting to do this likely indicates a misunderstanding of what records are for, so back up and think of other approaches".

Comment: @ksap What is your use case? Don't you know the record field names *at the time of writing your program*?

Answer (score 0):

If `defrecord` was a function, it would work. But `defrecord` is a macro. When you call it like this `(defrecord myRecord myFields)` it receives a symbol `myFields` rather than its value. Which is not what is expected. So validation fails.